# Alarm Manager- SetRepeating - INTERVAL_DAY not firing at all

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am trying to set an Alarm that goes off daily at 2:20 pm. Here is the code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,20);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        Intent intentService = new Intent(context, DownloadService.class);

        //setting alarm to run at 2:20 pm
        pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getService(context,0,intentService,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
```

When I use `5*60*1000` as the value for interval it works fine. But when I use `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY`, it doesn't go off. Can someone tell me if the code above is correct ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify, does even the initial alarm not go off or just the repetitions? Is all you're changing the interval, or are you making any other changes to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just oversaw the description in the INTERVAL_DAY:

> Available inexact recurrence interval recognized by
>   **setInexactRepeating**(int, long, long, PendingIntent) when running on
>   Android prior to API 19.

In your code your using **setRepeating not setInexactRepeating**
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY

Here is the difference in intervalMillis parameters:

setRepeating

> intervalMillis    interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats of
>   the alarm.

setInexactRepeating

> intervalMillis    interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats of
>   the alarm. Prior to API 19, if this is one of
>   INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR,
>   INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, or INTERVAL_DAY then the alarm will be
>   phase-aligned with other alarms to reduce the number of wakeups.
>   Otherwise, the alarm will be set as though the application had called
>   setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent). As of API 19, all
>   repeating alarms will be inexact and subject to batching with other
>   alarms regardless of their stated repeat interval.

Hope I helped good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line :

```
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,20);
```

with this line :

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,20);
```